# CSS: Bottom-aligning floated divs with percentage widths

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to figure out the correct CSS to vertically align the bottoms of two divs floated next to one another, as shown in the attached diagram. I would like to avoid having to absolutely position the divs with respect to width, as the the div marked "DIV.1" will contain text, and the width will vary based on text size/length. In fact, I would like to use percentage-based widths for all the divs if possible-- the DIV marked "DIV.2" will contain an image, and the site is to be responsive, so I'd like to use `max-width` and percentages when possible.

Thanks for any insight here.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A few ways to do this:

- Make the container element display:table and use [vertical alignment](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp)
- Use bottom: 0 to tie the div to the bottom of its container. This works with any element as long as it has set dimensions.
- set margins explicitly like the example above or set them as percentages.

  - Be careful with this though, margins use the percentage of the element, not the parent, when calculating size. So a half height div would have margin-top: 100%, not 50% of the container height as you might think.
- Use padding within the left div you bump your content down. This is probably the most straightforward and you don;t have to mess around with floats. Make sure you use a transparent background.

Comment: Thanks Tom; I'll configure a fiddle with your method and report back.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with margin-top and float see css code below.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/unknown601/g5x3cq1m/2/)

CSS

```
.col1{
width:200px;
height:600px;
background-color:#093;
position:relative;
    float:left;
}
.col2{
width:200px;
height:200px;
 margin-top:400px;
background-color:red;
position:relative;
float:left;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Timothy, only thing is I would prefer to not have to declare widths/heights if possible as I mentioned in my original post.

Comment: So you want it responsive?

Comment: responsive layouts has always been my weak spot.